# Strange code in clang API

Tags: c++, api, clang, llvm

I read source code clang API, and seen this code

```
00127   Optional<T> getAs() const {
00128     if (!T::isKind(*this))
00129       return None;
00130     T t;
00131     ProgramPoint& PP = t;
00132     PP = *this;
00133     return t;
00134   }
```

what does code on the lines 130-133? For what?
http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ProgramPoint_8h_source.html#l00127

Answer (score 1):

130: Create the return value, default initialized.

131: Create a reference to the return value.

132: Assign to the reference, using the assignment operator of ProgramPoint.
Didn't find one on first glance, so it's probably using the compiler generated assignment operator.

133: return it

The purpose of creating a reference could be one or more of:

- Check if T is a subclass of ProgramPoint
- Force use of the ProgramPoint assignment operator (and not of the subclass T) in line 132

Comment: Hi, Sebastian, Thanks for you answer. Could you explain why this function returns a local variable _t_, which seems irregular?